# Group by with "desc" not working with join

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have this table "chat"

```
id | id_user_1  | id_user_2
----------------------------
 1       111          117
 2       113          115    
 3       112          111
```

and this one, "messages":

```
id | message | message_date | id_sender | id_chat
-------------------------------------------------
 1      first     xx/xx/xx      111         1
 2      second    xx/xx/xx      117         1
 3      abc       xx/xx/xx      113         2
 4      first     xx/xx/xx      112         3
 5      second    xx/xx/xx      111         3
```

I need to list the last message of each user, I know there are other questions like this, but I could not find what am I doing wrong here; this is my query: (the issue is I get the first message, not the last of every user)

```
select t1.id, t2.message, t2.message_date
from chat as t1
join chat_messages as t2
where
(t1.id_user_1 = 111 or t1.id_user_2 = 111)
and
(t1.id = t2.id_chat)
group by t2.id_chat desc
```

This return:

```
 id | message | message_date | 
------------------------------
 3      first        xx/xx/xx   
 1      first        xx/xx/xx
```

When it should be:

```
 id | message | message_date | 
------------------------------
 3      second     xx/xx/xx   
 1      second     xx/xx/xx
```

Everything looks good, except for the part of "desc", which works before the join, but not after. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: `group by t2.id_chat desc` the desc go after `ORDER BY <fieldname> DESC` not group by. So I dont know how your query return data and not an error

Comment: Replace your t2.message  with `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t2.message ORDER BY t2.meesage_Date DESC),',',1)` if there are no aggregate functions you`ll have indeterminate values.

Comment: It is working, the resultset returned conforms to the specification... the value returned for `t2.message` is indeterminate. MySQL guarantees that the value returned will be from a row in the set that is "grouped" together by the `GROUP BY`. But MySQL is free to choose any row in that set. Other databases would throw a "non-aggregate in select list" error. MySQL has a non-standard extension that allows the statement to execute. But we can get MySQL to conform to the standard (and throw an error) by including ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in sql_mode.

Comment: that's interesting, and the solution proposed by @Mihai worked very good

Answer (score 0):

Not the best of solutions but you could try something simple like this:

```
select * from (select t1.id, t2.message, t2.message_date
from chat as t1
join messages as t2 on t1.id=t2.id_chat
where
(t1.id_user_1 = 111 or t1.id_user_2 = 111)
and
(t1.id = t2.id_chat)

order by message desc) a

group by id
```

If you have other requirements it could change completely

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dea13/8/0)

Comment: I'm getting the same results I got in the first place, the first comment, not the second, even if you replace the "order by message desc" with "order by t2.message_date desc".. in the sqlfiddle works, maybe cause is message, not message_date

Answer (score 0):

You can try by joining messages table to itself with the same chat id and greater message id.

```
SELECT c.id, m1.message, m1.message_date
FROM chat c 
LEFT JOIN messages m1 ON m1.id_chat = c.id
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON m2.id_chat = m1.id_chat AND m2.id > m1.id
WHERE m2.id IS NULL;
```

This will produce a result where in there is a `NULL` m2.id record. This record will indicate that this is the last message. so we can now fetch the last message for each chat using the WHERE condition

Answer (score 0):

The SQL scared me,you are so lazy! 
If I were you, I would obediently write sql this way:

```
select * from A a join B b on a.id=b.id group by a.message order by b.message desc
```

rather than:

```
select * from A a join B b where a.id=b.id group by a.message desc
```

I don't think the latter is explicit.